# How to fix score which depends on input amount and on select

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to create simple VAT calc in Javascript. It should work that first I set amount of money in #vat-amount then I pick .rate and then I could click one of two buttons which will show my results.

However my console shows that ReferenceError: rateValue is not defined. 
But I define it before I call brutto or netto function. What's wrong?

Here's my code & JSFiddle:

```
// Select your input element.
var fixnumber = document.getElementById('vat-amount');

// Listen for input event on numInput.
fixnumber.onkeydown = function(e) {
    if(!((e.keyCode > 95 && e.keyCode < 106)
      || (e.keyCode > 47 && e.keyCode < 58) 
      || (e.keyCode == 188)
      || e.keyCode == 8)) {
        return false;
    }
}

// Jquery function
$('.rate').on('change', function rateValue() {
    var value =this.value;
        if(value == 'five')
        {
          var ratemoney = 5
        }
        else if (value == 'eight') 
        {
            var ratemoney = 8
        }
        else {
            var ratemoney = 23
        }
    });

    var vatamount;
function setValues() { 
    vatamount = Number(document.getElementById("vat-amount").value);
}

function brutto() {
    setValues();
    rateValue();
    result = (vatamount * (ratemoney / 100) + vatamount);
    score = result.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById("howmuch").innerHTML = score;
}
function netto() {
    setValues();
    rateValue();
    result = (vatamount - ((ratemoney / 100) * vatamount));
    var score = result.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById("howmuch").innerHTML = score;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rq620kzo/2/

Sorry that I mix Jquery with Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved the rateValue function out to the scope you are trying to access it from. If you are going to modify values used outside of a function, don't redeclare them inside of the function

```js
// Select your input element.
var fixnumber = document.getElementById('vat-amount');

var ratemoney;

// Listen for input event on numInput.
fixnumber.onkeydown = function(e) {
  if (!((e.keyCode > 95 && e.keyCode < 106) ||
      (e.keyCode > 47 && e.keyCode < 58) ||
      (e.keyCode == 188) ||
      e.keyCode == 8)) {
    return false;
  }
}

// Jquery function
$('.rate').on('change', rateValue);

var vatamount;

function rateValue() {
  var value = $('.rate').val();
  if (value == 'five') {
    ratemoney = 5
  } else if (value == 'eight') {
    ratemoney = 8
  } else {
    ratemoney = 23
  }
}

function setValues() {
  vatamount = Number(document.getElementById("vat-amount").value);
}

function brutto() {
  setValues();
  rateValue();
  result = (vatamount * (ratemoney / 100) + vatamount);
  score = result.toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("howmuch").innerHTML = score;
}

function netto() {
  setValues();
  rateValue();
  result = (vatamount - ((ratemoney / 100) * vatamount));
  var score = result.toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("howmuch").innerHTML = score;
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.site-background {
  background: #cccccc;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  max-width: 70vw;
  background: #c1c1c1;
}

.first-vat-calc h2 {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="site-background">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Kalkulatory dla pracownika</h1>
    <h2>Oblicz VAT 23% </h2>
    <div class="first-vat-calc">
      <h2>Podaj kwotę</h2><input id="vat-amount" type="number" style="vat-money-input" pattern="[0-9]+([\.,][0-9]+)?" step="0.01" min="0">
      <h2>Podaj stawkę VAT</h2><select name="vatrate" class="rate" style="vat-money-input">
                    <option value="five">5%</option>
                    <option value="eight">8%</option>
                    <option value="twentythree">23%</option>
                  </select>
      <input type="button" onclick="brutto()" value="oblicz brutto">
      <input type="button" onclick="netto()" value="oblicz netto">
      <p>Wynik to:<span id="howmuch" style="howmuch" style="color: white;padding-left: 0,5vw;"></span></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for fixing my code.
That bring back to work buttons "oblicz brutto" and "oblicz netto" however it still doesnt fix my main problem which is to multiply amount by 5%, 8% or 23% using select

Comment: @David that's because the calls to `rateValue()`  are commented out in both `brutto()` and `netto()` uncomment them and it will work, i just removed the them in the code snippet run now and check

Comment: Nope, it's not helping, it's locked on 23% and I can't change values to 5% or 8%

Comment: David - You asked about an error and got answers with regards to that error. Don't expect all of your code to be debugged. That being said, you need to use .val(), not .value() in the rateValue function to get the value of the selected option. I've updated this answer so it isn't stuck on 23%.

Comment: Another way to make this cleaner is to either update the rate onchange or within the brutto and netto methods but you don't need it in both. Declare all of your variables at the top of the code and add documentation to explain what your functions do to improve your code even further.

Comment: Im sorry, my fault. Thanks for fixing my code @JasonB

Answer (score 0):

You cannot define named functions inside event handlers like that. Define it outside and you can call it from the handler.